# Is it possible to change element tooltip while old tooltip is already being shown wihout moving the mouse away and back

Tags: javascript, html

I have HTML anchor element: `<a title="Tooltip">Text</a>`. Then I mouse over the anchor and tooltip appears. Then I run some JavaScript to change tooltip via `element.title = "Another Tooltip"`. At this point tooltip is not changed by sight and I need to move mouse away and back to see the new tooltip. Is it possible to change tooltip immediatelly without moving mouse away and back?

Comment: You will have problems getting to to work with all browsers if you are using a title tag, why no try something like [Twitter Boostrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/) which provides tool tips you will beable to change.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should not use the `title` attribute, but some JavaScript tooltip library, for example [tipsy](http://onehackoranother.com/projects/jquery/tipsy/). This way, you have full control over the behaviour.